# Theming views block naming conventions

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views

I just try to style the block of a view called sidegalery.

I placed a file called block-views-sidegalery-block_1.tpl.php in my themes folder which is working.

But now I read in the views documentation and found that "Theme: Information" link in the views UI. There the filename views-view--sidegalery--block.tpl.php is suggested.

Is this more correct than my first attemp? What is the difference? And if both is correct which theme file will overwrite whom in the end?

Regards marcus

Answer (score 1):

The information listed under the "Theme:Information" suggests templates from generic to very specific for theming. By using the template "views-view--sidegalery--block.tpl.php", you will be theming all blocks in your "sidegalery" view the same way. By using the "block-views-sidegalery-block_1.tpl.php" template, it will only apply to that specific block, being block_1, the first block you have created in the view. The naming conventions only matter if you are creating multiple displays and want to theme them differently (or all the same).